# Represent hex to 64 byte (64 characters) in python

Tags: python

The results in "hex" are required to be completed with zeros.

example h = ed23
be represented like this
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ed23

Comment: 1 byte is 2 chars in hex. Anyway, look at the format strings and zero-padding. The link is https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Please add as an answer if it is solved instead of editing into the question

Answer (score 0):

solved with zfill()

```
hex = ed23
hex64character = hex.zfill(64)
print(hex64character)
>>>000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ed23
```